# focus a NSTextField

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a NSTextField and I want to set its content if I klick on a button and than set the cursor on this textfield at the end of the text so if someone klicks the button he could just begin to type.

Until now I use [NSTextField selectText] it selects this textfield but it selects the whole text so if someone just begins to type he'd lose all the text which alread is in the textfield.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Ok I found it out now :)

```
- (IBAction)focusInputField:(id)sender {
    [textField selectText:self];
    [[textField currentEditor] setSelectedRange:NSMakeRange([[textField stringValue] length], 0)];  
}
```

and in RubyCocoa it is:

```
def select_input_field
    @input.selectText self
    range = OSX::NSRange.new(@input.stringValue.length, 0)
    @input.currentEditor.setSelectedRange range
end
```

Answer (score 34):

or even easier

```
[yourTextField becomeFirstResponder];
```

Comment: The problem with that is that this selects all the text and if you begin to type the prepopulated text will be overwritten, I wanted to set the cursor behind the text.

Comment: This method is deprecated in 10.5, furthermore, if you read the documentation for this method it quite clearly states 'Never invoke this method directly.'

Comment: Good point, Alan, I've just removed a bunch of calls that were raising an exception for using becomeFirstResponder directly, using the 10.8 SDK.

Answer (score 11):

You'll want to do something like this:

```
[[self window] makeFirstResponder:[self yourTextField]];
```

Comment: This also selects the text :-/

Answer (score 3):

I am writing an ingame plugini, I were having a similar problem:

```
- (void)gotEvent:(NSEvent *)newEvent
{
  [mainWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
  [mainWindow makeFirstResponder:messageField];
  [mainWindow sendEvent:newEvent]; // will forward the typing event
}
```

this does the job :)

Comment: where do you call gotEvent from?

Answer (score 2):

Some time ago I did similar task. My solution was write down small category method for partial text selection for NSTextField. This method does job like original selectText: does (with setting focus to control).

```
@implementation NSTextField( SelExt )

-(void)selectTextRange:(NSRange)range
{
   NSText *textEditor = [self.window fieldEditor:YES forObject:self];
   if( textEditor ){
      id cell = [self selectedCell];
      [cell selectWithFrame:[self bounds] inView:self 
            editor:textEditor delegate:self
            start:range.location length:range.length];
   }
}

@end
```

with this method you may place text selection where you want and start typing right after that.